# Catch one word with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've a text stored in a value, and I only want to get the text after "eindformaat".
Here is the text:

```
$desc = 'Folder DIN A4 2-breuk altaarvouw
135g druk glanzend
4/4 kleurig (dubbelzijdige druk)
2-breuk altaarvouw

eindformaat: 29,7 cm x 41,9 cm
gevouwen eindformaat: 20,95 cm x 29,7 cm
gegevensformaat: 29,9 cm x 42,1 cm';
```

What I want is the value after "eindformaat". So this will be: 29,7 cm x 41,9 cm in this case.
I tried a lot of patterns with preg_replace. But none of them works for me.
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
preg_replace('/\/eindformaat\/.*/', '', $desc);
```

Can somebody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I think that your title is very misleading. Maybe you want to update it? It seems like you just want to get a substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace), but [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) for extracting. And then just leave out the escaped `\/` slashes, as those are not present in the text.

```
 preg_match('/eindformaat:(.*)/', $desc, $result);
 print $result[1];
```

You need `(.*)` in parens, so it becomes the result capture group `[1]`. Also `.*` is sufficient as it won't match beyond the linebreak without regex `/s` flag.

The actual advantage of a regex is that you can make it super-specific:

```
 preg_match('/eindformaat: ((\d+|,|cm|\s|x)+)/', $desc, $result);
```

And as [@Jpsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357611/345031) points out, if you really only want to match the first `eindformaat:`, not the second with a preceding word, then add an `^` anchor and the `/m` regex flag, like so:

```
 preg_match('/^eindformaat: ....../m', $desc, $result);
```

Comment: Will also catch 'gevouwen eindformaat'.

Comment: Good point. I don't know what either means, and the regex would just match the first anyway. But a `^` anchor might be sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regular expression, you can split the string into lines and then explode on `:` if present:

```
// Split lines
$lines = explode("\n", $desc);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  // Split the current line on :
  $parts = explode(":", $line);
  // If the : was present and we now have 2 segments
  // Print the second segment if the first was eidnformaat with whitespace trimmed
  if (isset($parts[1]) && $parts[0] == "eindformaat") {
    echo trim($parts[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $desc = preg_replace('/(\neindformaat:)[^\n]*/i', '$1', $desc);
```

This will delete the value after 'eindformaat:' (which seems to be what you wanted).
Otherwise, if you want to **retrieve** that value, you have to use preg_match.

**Edit:**
Here is a somewhat brighter version:

```
$desc = preg_replace('/^(eindformaat:).*/im', '$1', $desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should match it for you:

```
preg_match('/eindformaat:([a-zA-Z0-9. ,]+)/g', $desc, $result);
```

Your matches will be stored in an array in $result.

Comment: Will also catch 'gevouwen eindformaat'.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you get the position of the colon and take verything right of that and run it through trim() to lose the leading space?

```
$line = 'gevouwen eindformaat: 20,95 cm x 29,7 cm';

$the_bit_that_want = trim( substr($line, substr($line, ':') ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you'd do it with regex but try using strpos and substr to produce the results you need.

```
 $start_eindformaat = stripos($desc, 'eindformaat') + 13;

 $length_eindformaat = stripos($start_eindformaat , 'gevouwen eindformaat') - $start_eindformaat;

 $eindformaat = substr($desc, $start_eindformaat, $length_eindformaat
```